# how to know in which region is the markers using leaflet map

Tags: count, leaflet, contains, markers

I want to the count of markers based on location using leaflet map
ie,
Say in india

Number of markers in bangalore
number of makers in mysore so on...

only thing i would think of  to do this is  using contains(  point ) 
which is in the doc

But how to use it to find the maker is in that region as i will not be aware of the coordinates of the region

Is there a way to check like

```
 region.contains(markerLatLang)
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaflet `.contains()` works on `L.LatLngBounds` objects, which are actually a rectangular region. So it tells if your point / marker is within a rectangle or not.

You would need first to retrieve yourself the coordinates of your administrative areas of interest (India, etc.). See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199765/where-to-get-world-wide-detailed-administrative-boundaries

BTW, a simple version of countries boundaries can be: https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json

Then you would probably want to use a more accurate detection method, for example leaflet-pip plugin or turf.js, which will actually check if your point is within arbitrarily shaped polygons, not just a rectangle.

See for instance [Leaflet event: how to propagate to overlapping layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43007019/leaflet-event-how-to-propagate-to-overlapping-layers/43011920?r=SearchResults#43011920)