# Leaflet: How can I simulate a mouse click? fireevent('click') does not trigger the popup

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I would like to simulate a mouse click in javascript with leaflet.

I have a map with a few different layers. Some activate popups.
When I click on an item with the mouse, a popup comes up.

When I try to execute the following code, it seems to "click" at the desired location but no popup comes up.

```js
map.fireEvent('click', {
    latlng: L.latLng(lat, lng)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your layers' popup will open only if the layers receive the click event.

When you do `map.fire('click')`, only the map gets the event, not the layers on it, even if they are at the Lat/Lng position you specified.

In order to find which layers are at the specified Lat/Lng position, you can use for example [leaflet-pip](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip) plugin (point in polygon):

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([48.86, 2.35], 11);

var geoJSONdata = {
  type: 'Feature',
  geometry: {
    type: 'Polygon',
    coordinates: [
      [
        [2.3, 48.85],
        [2.3, 48.87],
        [2.4, 48.87],
        [2.4, 48.85],
        [2.3, 48.85]
      ]
    ]
  }
}

var geoJsonLayerGroup = L.geoJSON(geoJSONdata, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup('Popup')
  }
}).addTo(map);

document.getElementById('pipClick').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var latlng = L.latLng([48.86, 2.35]);
  // Use Mapbox Leaflet PIP (point in polygon) library.
  var foundLayers = leafletPip.pointInLayer(latlng, geoJsonLayerGroup);

  foundLayers.forEach(function(layer) {
    layer.fire('click', {
      latlng: latlng
    });
  });
});

document.getElementById('mapClick').addEventListener('click', function() {
  map.fire('click', {
    latlng: L.latLng([48.86, 2.35])
  });
});

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-pip@1.1.0/leaflet-pip.js"></script>

<button id="mapClick">Click on Map</button>
<button id="pipClick">Find layers with PIP and click them</button>
<div id="map" style="height: 170px"></div>
```

Comment: is there a way to find the layers from a physical 'click' event without using a plugin?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean, but you might be interested in event's [`target`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#event-target) and/or [`layer`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojsonevent-layer) properties. You might also be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43007019/leaflet-event-how-to-propagate-to-overlapping-layers/43011920#43011920. Please open a new question should you need further help for this different question.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @ghybs answer:
Leaflet layer have a `fireEvent` [method](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#layer-fireevent), you can use it to trigger layer events.